# Errors with codes for deleting using linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, combobox

I encounter a problem regarding the deleting of data using combo box. The error prompted me I have no idea of how to solve it. Anyone can help me about it?

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
    {
        var Lo = Convert.ToInt16(cbLocationData.SelectedValue);
        var DeleteLocation = (from delLocation in Setupctx.locations
                              where delLocation.Location1 == Lo
                              select delLocation).Single();
        Setupctx.DeleteObject(DeleteLocation);
        Setupctx.SaveChanges();
        this.Delete_Location_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Shift Timing Has Been Deleted.");
    }
}
```

The part `where delLocation.Location1 == Lo` showing me the following error

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'short'.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to make sure it is getting into your foreachloop?

Comment: Your  event is firing on SelectedindexChanged of the cb you're trying to fill. Try putting it in the page load or a more appropriate place?

Comment: @Ghost thanks for reminding. I moved my codes to Page_Load and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: I think you put your code in wrong place.. and I agree with @Ghost

Answer (score 1):

Create a method something like this:

```
private void LoadLocation()
{
       using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            var storeLocation = (from vL in Setupctx.locations
                                 select new
                                         {
                                           Location1  =vL.Location1
                                         }
                                 );

                cbLocationData.DataTextField = "Location1";
                cbLocationData.DataSource = storeLocation;
                cbLocationData.DataBind();

        }
}
```

Then on your page load(asp.net)/form Load(winform) add:

```
           LoadLocation();
```

Hope this help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cbLocationData_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
    {
        var storeLocation = (from vL in Setupctx.locations
                             where vL.Location1 == vL.Location1
                             select vL.Location1);

        foreach (var locationData in storeLocation)
        {
            cbLocationData.Items.Add(locationData.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible that locationData needs set to tostring() or convert(), depending on the data type? Everything looks like it should be working correctly.

Comment: I tried your way but it still seems that the combo box does not have any data inside.

Answer (score 0):

Your event is firing on SelectedindexChanged of the cb you're trying to fill. Try putting it in the page load or a more appropriate place?

Answer (score 0):

I think you put your code in wrong place.. 
you just add items on same combo select change (cbLocationData_SelectedIndexChanged) 
that's wrong
put your code other appropriate place in which adding items are not part of same events