# Error with codes for deleting using linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, combobox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Errors with codes for deleting using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444719/errors-with-codes-for-deleting-using-linq)

I encounter a problem regarding the deleting of data using combo box. The error prompted me I have no idea of how to solve it. Anyone can help me about it?

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            var Lo = Convert.ToInt16(cbLocationData.SelectedValue);
            var DeleteLocation = (from delLocation in Setupctx.locations
                                  where delLocation.Location1 == Lo
                                  select delLocation).Single();
            Setupctx.DeleteObject(DeleteLocation);
            Setupctx.SaveChanges();
            this.Delete_Location_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Shift Timing Has Been Deleted.");
        }
    }
```

The part `where delLocation.Location1 == Lo` showing me the error

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'short'.".

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

The answer to the above question is below

```
 private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            string selectLo = cbLocationData.SelectedItem.ToString();

            var DeleteLocation = (from delLocation in Setupctx.locations
                                  where delLocation.Location1 == selectLo
                                  select delLocation).SingleOrDefault();
            if (DeleteLocation != null)
            {
                Setupctx.DeleteObject(DeleteLocation);
                Setupctx.SaveChanges();
                cbLocationData.SelectedIndex = -1;
                this.Delete_Location_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                MessageBox.Show("Selected Shift Timing Has Been Deleted.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i'm not wrong it shoud be single "=" for equality in linq ?

Comment: @WaqarJanjua nope, you're wrong :)

Comment: Yea sing "=" cannot work that's why I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

It means you cannot *compare* `delLocation.Location1` and `Lo` because they are of different data types. Try:

```
where delLocation.Location1.Equals(Lo.ToString())
```

Comment: I tried your way but still have error prompting that 'LINQ to Entities' does not recognise your method...'

Comment: @Philemon Can you try the edited answer now?

Comment: Still prompting me the same error.

Comment: Can you check if either `delLocation.Location1` or `Lo` is null?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `Location1` is a `string`, which cannot be directly compared to a `short` using `==`.  Instead of converting `Lo` to a `short`, and then back to a `string`, try:

```
var Lo = (string)cbLocationData.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: They prompt me a error "Sequence contains no element."

Comment: Is it possible there really is no item in `Setupctx.locations` with a matching string value? If it is possible they match but differ in casing, you migth try using `String.Compare` instead of the `==` operator. String.Compare has overloads that let you ignore some differences.

Answer (score 1):

The error says you are trying to compare a string to an Int16. Since we already know Lo is an Int16, delLocation.Location1 has to be the string. So to solve this, you remove the `Convert.ToInt16()` (since the `SelectedValue` of a dropdownlist is string)  like this:

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
    {
        var Lo = Convert.ToString(cbLocationData.SelectedValue);
        var DeleteLocation = (from delLocation in Setupctx.locations
                              where delLocation.Location1 == Lo
                              select delLocation).Single();
        Setupctx.DeleteObject(DeleteLocation);
        Setupctx.SaveChanges();
        this.Delete_Location_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Shift Timing Has Been Deleted.");
    }
}
```

### Update

If you get an error "Sequence contains no element", that means your query did not return any results and you can't do `Single()` on an empty sequence. You can use `SingleOrDefault()` and then check if the value is null or not like this:

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
    {
        var Lo = Convert.ToString(cbLocationData.SelectedValue);
        var DeleteLocation = (from delLocation in Setupctx.locations
                              where delLocation.Location1 == Lo
                              select delLocation).SingleOrDefault();
        if (DeleteLocation != null)
        {
            Setupctx.DeleteObject(DeleteLocation);
            Setupctx.SaveChanges();
            this.Delete_Location_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Shift Timing Has Been Deleted.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This most likely will give a wrong result. `cbLocationData.SelectedValue` is an object. If you don't cast it to a string, you're comparing references, not strings.

Comment: @Kristof I have tried your way also but a error prompting me that 'Sequence contains no element.'

Comment: @ErenErsönmez any idea of how to get this code done? I'm real lost right now.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I have tried it and error prompting me 'Sequence contains no element".

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: You are right. I thought Philemon was using ASP.NET. There the selectedvalue of a dropdownlist is a string. In WinForms it is indeed an object.

Comment: @Philemon: I updated my answer to address the "Sequence contains no element" issue.

Comment: After trying out your edited solution, when i select and clicked on the delete button, nothing happens.

Comment: That's because DeleteLocation is null. It means there is no Location whose Location1 property equals the SelectedValue of the cbLocationData.

Comment: @KristofClaes but from the location table where delLocation.Location1 is the column name in the location table. Maybe the data doesn't pass down?

Comment: @Philemon: I have no idea what you just said :-) What you need to do is debug the `btnDel_Click` method, look at the value of `Lo` and see if there is a Location in your database with a Location1 value that equals the value of `Lo`. Or install EFProf (http://www.efprof.com) to see what query is being issued against your database.